# In Unix how would I copy /etc/passwd using relative path to a directory under my home directory?

Tags: shell-script, cp

I am required to copy the `/etc/passwd` to a directory, I have already created, with the new name `my_passwd`. I understand how to copy it with an absolute path: `cp /etc/passwd /home/user/work/my_passwd`.

So I understand that `.` is where I am in the shell, and `..` is used to move me up one in the directory I am in and I typed `cd work` and i can move there if I am in home? Am I wrong and how would I go about copying with a relative path?

Comment: (1) This smells like homework.  What sort of real-world situation would “require” you to use relative paths for doing something where the use of an absolute path is the natural way to do it?  (2) Questions like this come up frequently.  Have you done any research?

Comment: I never stated it wasn't. I also did quite a bit of looking and everyone's explanation either didn't make sense or ignored the relative path copy. Also a lot of the questions that were similar on here were poorly asked or produced answers that were above my head. @G-Man

Comment: The *other* questions were poorly asked?  What do *you* mean by “copy /etc/passwd using relative path” and “copying with a relative path”? `/etc/passwd` is, of course, an absolute path, so it’s not clear what your question means if ``cp /etc/passwd …`` is what you were looking for.

Comment: This might be somehow sensible, if we assume the work is being done inside `/chroots/$foo/home/user/`, and they want to access the file `/chroots/$foo/etc/something` ...

Comment: @ilkkachu: Good point. Having a root filesystem mounted somewhere other than ``/`` is a real-world situation where this sort of information might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relative path is a path that does not start with `/`.

In this particular example, `/etc/passwd` is an absolute path, and if you know the absolute path of a file that you want to copy *there is (often) no practical purpose of converting it into a relative path* (in fact, it may just confuse things since the path depends on where in the directory tree you are currently located).

The directory that you'd like to copy the file to is `$HOME/work` with the filename `my_passwd`.  `$HOME` will expand to the absolute path of your home directory.

To copy the file using only absolute paths:

```
cp /etc/passwd "$HOME/work/my_passwd"
```

This does not depend where in the filesystem you are presently located (which is nice).

To find the relative path to the `/etc/passwd` file, you may use the `realpath` command on Linux (this utility may not be available on other types of Unix systems, and it's available in at least Ubuntu).  Assuming that you are located in you home directory (after giving the command `cd` with no arguments):

```
$ realpath --relative-to=. /etc/passwd
../../etc/passwd
```

This tells us that "`/etc/passwd` is located two directories up from here, and then down in `etc`".

To copy the file using relative paths, from being located in your home directory (it will not work from other places in the directory tree):

```
$ cp ../../etc/passwd work/my_passwd
```

`work/my_passwd` is the relative path from your home directory to the file `my_passwd` in the `work` subdirectory.

Ether combination of

```
$ cp /etc/passwd work/my_passwd
```

or

```
$ cp ../../etc/passwd "$HOME/work/my_passwd"
```

would obviously also work (from you home directory) depending on which of the paths you'd like to specify absolutely or relatively.

Comment: (1) That `realpath` command is a neat trick. But we don’t really know what the OP is doing. If they’re really doing what they say they’re doing, and they’re just trying to learn how to construct relative paths, this is probably useful. But if, [as ilkkachu suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421125/80216#comment757450_421125), they’re really trying to copy `/mnt/etc/passwd` to `/mnt/home/user/work/my_passwd`, it will backfire, as it will end up pointing to the real `/etc/passwd`. Compare to [ilkkachu’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421125/80216#421203), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  which *explains* that the user needs to count directory levels. (2) I suspect that the OP and similar people could read your answer and not understand that `$HOME` *is* an absolute path, even though it appears not to begin with a `/`.

Comment: @G-Man (1) We only have what the user says, and they say they need to copy `/etc/passwd` to a subdirectory in their home directory, under a new name. I find it highly unlikely that a user, new to the shell, is dealing with a chroot.

Comment: @G-Man (2) I _did_ say that "`$HOME` will expand to the absolute path of your home directory.".

Answer (score 1):

How to make a relative path to `/etc/passwd`? Make a relative path to `/`, and then add `etc/passwd`. How to make a relative path to `/`? Count the depth of your current directory, and go towards the root that many steps.

So, if we're in `/home/user/work`, we go towards the root three times with `../../../`. Programmatically, either count the slashes in the current path, or just replace all directory names with `..`, and move the first slash to the end.

Let's do the latter in Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
p=${PWD//+([^\/])/..}
p=${p#/}/
echo "current is: $PWD"
echo "path to /:  $p"
```

The output is e.g. :

```
current is: /tmp/x
path to /:  ../../
```

Perhaps a more practical situation would be one where we need a relative path from `/foo/bar/some/path` to `/foo/bar/otherpath`, in which case just drop the common prefix and apply the solution above.

Comment: @G-Man, err, yeah. I suppose you're right. (Though right now, any choice feels confusing, even "go left to the root" seems equally right.) Reworded.